# Do we need tags [dfa] and [nfa]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Recently, people have started using [dfa](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dfa) for tagging some [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata) questions.

Do we really need this tag, or should it be a synonym for [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata)?

The question can be asked in principle about [nfa](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfa), but nobody used this so far. We *do* have [nondeterminism](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nondeterminism).

Answer (score 7):

I think [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata) is specific enough, even for questions that aim towards getting a DFA. That is because determinism is (usually) not the issue; every NFA can be algorithmically converted into a DFA. The issue is finding *any* finite automaton.

For questions that specifically deal with nondeterminism, we already have [nondeterminism](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nondeterminism) (which can be used with any machine-model tag).

Therefore, I think [dfa](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dfa) and [nfa](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfa) (proactively) are obsolete. I proposed them as synonyms of [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata); if you agree, [please upvote them](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/finite-automata/synonyms).

Comment: Since there were no comments or votes against, and three upvotes on both synonyms, I'm mod-approving them.